how to get actual hyperparameter of a fitted model?
I like to get the actual hyperparameters of a RandomForestClassifier fitted with default settings. get_params() is not helpful.
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
rfc.fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)

rfc.get_params()

{'bootstrap': True,
 'ccp_alpha': 0.0,
 'class_weight': None,
 'criterion': 'gini',
 'max_depth': None,
 'max_features': 'sqrt',
 'max_leaf_nodes': None,
 'max_samples': None,
 'min_impurity_decrease': 0.0,
 'min_samples_leaf': 1,
 'min_samples_split': 2,
 'min_weight_fraction_leaf': 0.0,
 'n_estimators': 100,
 'n_jobs': None,
 'oob_score': False,
 'random_state': None,
 'verbose': 0,
 'warm_start': False}

For example, how to get actual max_depth of the fitted model?
